# Make a .div act like an image

Tags: css, image, overflow, contain

I have a question about the display of a container.

First, I managed to simulate the attribute "object-fit: contain;" for an image by using a  verticaly alligned strut and the attribute "text-align: center" (thank you IE).

> See it there: http://codepen.io/babybackart/pen/vGQeoK

html:

```
<body>
   <div class="plancheBox">
      <div class="strut"></div><!--
      --><img src="http://images.forwallpaper.com/files/thumbs/preview/23/236747__kitten-soft-fluffy-tender_p.jpg">
   </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   text-align:center;
}

h1, h2{
   font-family: Arial, sans serif;
   font-weight: 300;
   color: white;
}

.plancheBox{
   background-color: green;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width: 90%;
   height: 90%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.strut {
   height:100%;
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:middle;
}

.plancheBox img{
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I wanted to add a text on the image so I put the image and a text-box in a bloc (the text-box is absolute to appear in front of the image).

> See it there: http://codepen.io/babybackart/pen/BKGwZL

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="plancheBox">
    <div class="strut"></div><!--
    --><div class="container">
          <img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/photo-cat-1.jpg">
          <div class="descriptionBox">
             <h1>Joe le chat</h1>
             <h2>Post haec Gallus Hierapolim profecturus ut expeditioni specie tenus adesset, Antiochensi plebi suppliciter obsecranti ut inediae dispelleret metum, quae per multas difficilisque causas adfore iam sperabatur.</h2>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}

h1, h2{
  font-family: Arial, sans serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
}

.plancheBox{
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.strut {
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.container{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.container img{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.descriptionBox{
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 20% 5% 20%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The problem is that my .div ".container" doesn't act like my image in the first example, it overflows on the bottom when the windows' height is small.

Main question: **Is there a way to make the ".container" act like the image in the first example ?**

Extra-question: How to fix the ratio and the size of the text-box with the size of the image?

Thank you by advance for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to size the container according to it's content and the content according to it's parent at the same time. This does not work. One of it needs to have set some dimensions.
According to your examples it's the image, that should be fit into an container, so I dimension the container and let the image be sized according to it.

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    height: 100%; /* not max-height */
    width: 100%; /* not max-width */
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.container img {
    max-height: 100.1%; /* ".1" just to avoid small lines due to browser rendering */
    max-width: 100.1%; /* ".1" just to avoid small lines due to browser rendering */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The `position: absolute` is needed to "fit" the image inside your container an position it at the same time. The `50%` moves the top-left border of the image to the center of the container, and the `transform` moves the image by half its width and height back - so it's centered.

---

Since the above is outdated as per the more information provided by the OP. You'd need additional JS for that:

**JS:**

```
$('.plancheBox img').each( function() {

  var $img = $(this),
      $plancheBox = $img.closest('.plancheBox');

  $img.css({
    'max-height' : $plancheBox.height(),
    'max-width'  : $plancheBox.width()
  });

  $img.closest('.container').css({'position' : 'relative'});

});
```

**CSS:**

```
[...]

.container{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.container img{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.descriptionBox{
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 20%;
  left: 20%;
}

[...]
```

example fiddle:  [jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/2](https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/2)

---

In case a portrait ***plancheBox*** is possible: [jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/3](https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/3)

---

When resizing the browser should be considered by JS, add an event handler, that resets the css-changes and calculate the needed values again.
See: [jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/4](https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/4)

**JS:**

```
// calculateImageDimension() contains the JS described above

var resizeEnd;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeEnd);
  resizeEnd = setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize-end');
  }, 200);
});

$(window).on('resize-end', function() {

    $('.plancheBox img').css({
    'max-height' : 'none',
    'max-width'  : 'none'
  })
  $('.plancheBox .container').css({'position' : ''});

  calculateImageDimension();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Seika85 for your answer, your solution works for the image.

The problem is that I needed a container that resizes in the same time as the image in order to fix the text-box according to it. 
With a 100% container, It will be impossible to fix the text-box to the image. This solution is equivalent to not use a container at all for the image and the text-Box. (I hope that I'm clear enough)

Comment: You want an image-wrapper which sizes itself according to the containing image, but at the same time respects it's parents dimensions which shall be passed along to the image to size that. This is not possible with pure CSS. You would need JS for that as I used in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/2/

Comment: I understand the struggle with my question which seems contradictory...
I actually need a text-box fixed to an image that resizes in function of its container. Maybe I can fix the text-box to the image by using JS without using a container so the image will fit in the ".plancheBox" without overflow like in the first example ?

Comment: I understand your question, but to make a text-box depending on a pictures dimensions, you need a container wrapping both. This container you want on one hand side to size itself according to the containing image, and on the other hand side to not exceed its parents dimensions. And that is not possible with pure CSS. You would need at least one element with a fixed width/height. So the only option left is to use JS as I already did in my fiddle.

Comment: If I understand well your JS part, you fixed the max-height and the max-width of the image according to the dimensions of the plancheBox. When I try your solution, the image doesn't resizes but is cut according to the plancheBox. The part of the image that overflows is just hidden by the " overflow: hidden;" attribute on the plancheBox.

Comment: Did you add all the changed CSS? Please provide a fiddle, so I can work on that basis. (I don't have a codepen account.)

Comment: I was talking about the fiddle you sent me : https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/2/
The image is cut instead of resized

Comment: For me it's working: http://i.imgur.com/AaLZDen.png (Screenshot).  
I tested it in Chrome 50, FF 45 and IE 11. (Updated the fiddle in case of portrait plancheBox: https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/3/)

Comment: On chrome 50: http://imgur.com/a/2YAH7. Try other dimensions, in the photo you sent me, the height of the plancheBox is exactly the initial size of the picture. If you reduce de dimensions, it will cut the images.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that the code was working only after a refresh of the page. When I resize the window after the loading of the page, it cuts the image but it is resized after a refresh. Is there a way to make it work without a refresh ?

Comment: That's because the values applied by JS are only applied once initial. If you want them to recalculate on resize, you have to add an event handler for that. In this handler, you remove all the changes made by the JS and rerun the calculation. See: https://jsfiddle.net/jpu8umd6/4/

Comment: Nothing more to say, looks like you're my hero Seika85. I will try to insert it in my website. Thank you very much for the time you spent on my problem.

Comment: I asked another question for the integration of your code on a website using fullPage.js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034518/js-image-resize-compatible-with-fullpage-js

Answer (score 0):

Since `.descriptionBox` has `position: absolute;` the (surrounding) `.container` should probably have `position:relative;`

https://codepen.io/eye-wonder/pen/EKGPmZ

Comment: Do you see the difference in the image size with your example and the first codepen OP posted? Because that's what he tries to accomplish.
In your example the image overlaps the wanted dimensions and the wrapping elements scale according to its children.

Comment: Thank you @eye-wonder for your answer, You are right, the position:relative of the container allowed me to fix the text-Box to the picture. However, it doesn't seem to solve the cut of the image. When the windows' height is small, the image still overflows out of the container (you can see it if you set the opacity of the image to 0.5).

Comment: Safari (9) and Firefox (44) os x render my codepen differently. I can not see the image is cut in any of them. If I scroll the page the whole image is visible.

Comment: Try add `overflow:hidden` to the ***plancheBox*** element in your example to see what we mean. Because of the percentage dimensions of all parent container above the image, the containers are either stretched to it's content (the image) or are just overflown by it. But that's not what OP wants. He/she wants an Container with variable dimensions (depending only on its parent) and an image sizing itself to fit it (like `background-size:contain`). But additionally there should be a caption as well, which should not exceed the dimensions of the (contained) image. And that is the actual struggle.

Comment: As far as I can see, Firefox and Chrome does not fit the height of the plancheBox/image to the height of the window. Safari seem to do this.