# JS image resize compatible with fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, compatibility, fullpage.js

I am trying to integrate this code : http://codepen.io/babybackart/pen/GZPjJd on a section of a website using fullpage.js.

*This code is based on a previous question brilliantly answered by @Seika85 : [Make a .div act like an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983773/make-a-div-act-like-an-image).
The aim was to "contain" and resize the image on its container ".plancheBox" without cuting it.*

In this example, the cat picture's dimensions are driven by the container using this first javascript code:

```
var calculateImageDimension = function() {

  $('.plancheBox img').each(function() {

    var $img = $(this),
      $plancheBox = $img.closest('.plancheBox');

    $img.css({
      'max-height': $plancheBox.height() + 2,
      /* (+2px) prevent thin margins due to rendering */
      'max-width': $plancheBox.width()
    });

    $img.closest('.container').css({
      'position': 'relative'
    });

  });
}

calculateImageDimension();
```

In order to set these dimensions instantaneously (without a page refresh), I am using this second javascript code:

```
var resizeEnd;
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeEnd);
  resizeEnd = setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize-end');
  }, 200);
});

$(window).on('resize-end', function() {

  $('.plancheBox img').css({
    'max-height': 'none',
    'max-width': 'none'
  })
  $('.plancheBox .container').css({
    'position': ''
  });

  calculateImageDimension();
});
```

As you can see in the first example, it works without fullpage.js.

I managed to insert the first JS code in a fullpage.js website : http://codepen.io/babybackart/pen/ONrbEN but I don't really manage to insert the second one.

I'm not actually a JS coder so I wanted to know what I needed to do to insert this code, if it was possible to do this with fullpage.js and if there were any conflict between both codes.

Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second JS code must be inserted in a fullPage event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //events
        afterResize: function(){
            $('.plancheBox img').css({
            'max-height' : 'none',
            'max-width'  : 'none'
          })
          $('.plancheBox .conteneur').css({'position' : ''});

          calculateImageDimension();
        }
    });
});
```