# Automatic width relative to height + resizing the window

Tags: css

I'm building a web application in which I want a specific element to scale relative to it's parent. As far as I know, the only way to achieve this without using javascript is to use an image with the desired aspect ratio (there have been several other Stackoverflow posts about this issue), which is what I have done, so basically this:

```
div { height:20%; display:inline-block; }
div img { height:100%; }
```

This causes the div to scale the way I want, but the problem is that when the browser is resized, the width of the image changes, but the width of the div doesn't.. After refreshing the page, the element will be scaled properly again.

I've made a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1efuzmb/ You can see the issue when you resize your browser or the "output" column on the Jsfiddle website.

Some notes:

- The issue only occurs in Chrome and IE. In Firefox and Safari the div is scaling correctly.
- I could use vh-units to set the width, but since I'm trying to scale this element relative to it's parent and not the viewport, it's not really ideal.

Does anyone know if this is a browser issue and/or if there's a way to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a parent element with only height defined and want the child to determine the width? Mind telling us what this "specific element" is?

Comment: I'm creating a cardgame. There's a "bar" on the bottom of the page which has a height of 20% relative to the body. This bar contains items ("cards"), which I want to give a height of 100% relative to the "bar", but containing their aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding-top on the before pseudo element to get the same effect as if you would have used an image.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, since this would scale the height relative to the element's width. I'm trying to do the exact opposite :)

Answer (score 0):

`div img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}`

The image will fill the container with its proper aspect ratio.

Comment: This would work if the container would have a width and I would want an automatic height. I'm trying to achieve the exact opposite.

Comment: @Leon sorry I guess I misunderstood this issue. Here is another tip: If you're using an image just to behave the way you want, why don't you use Flexbox model for these cards?

Answer (score 0):

I think that by using float and let the image-container always be 20vh could be a possible solution in your case.

```css
html, body { 
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.card-container { 
  height:20vh; 
  display:inline-block; 
  background-color:red;
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color:lightgray;
}
.cards{ 
  height: 20vh;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.cards:after{ 
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;}

.cards img { 
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  height:100%; 
  width:auto; 
  padding:0 2px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="cards">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150/">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the "card" needs to be a div, so that I can apply other styles to it, I can't use an image for this. I'm merely using the image to resize the div..

Comment: I see, have you seen this q? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983773/make-a-div-act-like-an-image